# Rewriting my dynamic url in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a problem in rewriting my dynamic url pattern in localhost.

here is my url: http://localhost/realtor/?module=property&action=popular-residential-buy
and i want the url to be http://localhost/realtor/property/popular-residential-buy

I have done so far in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule type (.*)-(.*)$ /?module=$1&action=$2
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing regular expression gobbles up too much of your URL. You'll end up with something other than what you want in $1 and $2 (probably `realtor/property/popular-residential` in $1, and just `buy` in $2, due to the first .* greedily matching as much as it can before back tracking one character at a time to find a match).

Based on the URL you provided, it looks like your regular expression should be something like `^realtor/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$`. That will give you what you want in $1 and $2, and it should be a quicker regular expression AFAIK.

Past that, make sure that you do have the RewriteEngine properly configured on your particular server.

- For Apache, you'll need to enable mod_rewrite. Look in your httpd.conf for `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`, and make sure it is uncommented.
- IIS is a bigger can of worms -- let me know if that is what you are using, and I will write a more complete answer.